# Use of spring security jstl tag <sec:authority access="hasPermission(#domain, 'permission')> inside a jstl core loop

Tags: spring, spring-security, jstl, spring-el

I'm using facelets (JSF2.1) and I'm trying to do something like:

```
<c:forEach var="domainObject" items="#{MB.listOfDomainObjects}">
    <sec:authorize access="hasPermission(#domainObject,'PERMISSION_X')">
        hello world
    </sec:authorize>
</c:forEach>
```

I've tried changing `#domainObject` by `@domainObject`, `#{domainObject}`, `$domainObject` and a lot of other combinations with the same result: `domainObject` is not processed correctly. Sometimes I get an error saying the page cannot be constructed, others `domainObject` is null.

It's like the scope where the tag `c:forEach` puts the variable `domainObject` is not scanned by `sec:authorize` to find it.

I've tried also to force the use of a scope using the tag `<c:set ... scope="view"/>`. I've also tried to use `<ui:repeat>` with the same results, but considering the tag `sec:authorize` is a jstl one, I suppose is [executed in build time (like `c:forEach`) and not in render time (like `ui:repeat`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense/#3343681), so I think I must use `c:foreach` and not `ui:repeat`.

Any chance to solve my problem?